# How to solve recursion problem in the merge-sort algorithm?

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

In the exmple, I want to sort the attribute f of station by using the merge-sort.

```
class mergesort_algorithm():


 def Merge_Sort(self,stations):

     length = len(stations)
     middle = int(length/2-1)

     if length<=1:
         return stations
     else:
         list1 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[:middle])
         list2 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[middle:])

         return self.Merge(list1,list2)




 def Merge(self,list1,list2):
     list3 = []
     length1 = len(list1)
     length2 = len(list2)
     point1 = 0
     point2 = 0


     while point1<=length1-1 and point2<=length2-1:

         if list1[point1].f<list2[point2].f:
             list3.append(list1[point1])
             point1 += 1

         else:
             list3.append(list2[point2])
             point2 += 1

     if point1>length1:
         for i in range(list2):
             if i>=point2:
                 list3.append(list2[point2])

     if point2>length2:
         for i in range(list1):
             if i>=point1:
                 list3.append(list1[point1])

     for item in list3:
         print(item.name)
     print("-----")
     return list3
```

When I run the codes to sort the stations list, It reports the error.

```
File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Util/Mergesort_algorithm.py", line 16, in Merge_Sort
    list1 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[:middle])
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Util/Mergesort_algorithm.py", line 17, in Merge_Sort
    list2 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[middle:])
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Util/Mergesort_algorithm.py", line 17, in Merge_Sort
    list2 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[middle:])
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Util/Mergesort_algorithm.py", line 17, in Merge_Sort
    list2 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[middle:])
  [Previous line repeated 989 more times]
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Util/Mergesort_algorithm.py", line 16, in Merge_Sort
    list1 = self.Merge_Sort(stations[:middle])
  File "/home/surface/Final-Year-Project/FYP/Util/Mergesort_algorithm.py", line 11, in Merge_Sort
    middle = int(length/2-1)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I don't know how to solve it. It seems that there are so many recursions. And I find some solution use:
 **import sys** and **sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)**

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: Middle should be `middle = len(stations)//2 #Finding the mid of the array` as in other [merge sort algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/)

Comment: @mkrieger1 A little complex, it's a function in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `len(stations)` is 2. Then `middle` is 0. So `stations[:middle]` is empty, but `stations[middle:]` has length 2 and there's an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about the case in the past!